# Getting records only if eager loaded condition met in laravel elequent

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.3.30 and facing the current problem. I tried to search everywhere and did not find any related solution to what I exactly need. So please before mark this as duplicate make sure you read my question carefully.

**Tables:** [clients], [messages]

**Relation:** clients has many messages

**What I'm trying to achieve is:**
Getting all clients who his last message (contact_date) is less than 1 week from now.

**I tried many things including the following:**

```
Client::whereHas('messages', function($query){
    $query->orderBy('contact_date', 'desc')
    ->whereDate('contact_date', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
})->get();
```

This is the best option I have tell now, but it is not satisfy my needs.

This will check for all (contact_date)s of a client and will retrieve any client who have a message less than the required date.

**My question is:**
How I can apply this only for the latest [messages] record? Suppose I have 100 messages for each client and want to apply this only on the latest message. So, if the message condition does not met, the query will not retrieve the client.

Comment: A groupBy on messages grouping by account_id?

Comment: @chasenyc you mean by client_id, yes I tried it still getting the client even though his last message is greater than the date set in the constraint, Than because the client have other messages less than that date. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong could you illustrate please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to do a subquery to join only dates older than specified date:

```
Client::select('clients.*')
  ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT messages.* FROM messages WHERE contact_date < {$date})'), function($join) 
    {
      $join->on('clients.id', '=', 'messages.client_id');
    })
    ->groupBy('messages.client_id')
    ->orderBy('contact_date', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I'm not sure this code will work perfectly as is but it should give you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: unfortunately, sub query join also get the same results as it checks the older dates of messages. I only want the latest message of each client. Client::select('clients.*') ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT messages.* FROM messages WHERE contact_date < "'. Carbon::now()->subDays(7) .'") As SubQuery'), function($join){ $join->on('clients.id', '=', 'SubQuery.client_id'); })->groupBy('SubQuery.client_id')->orderBy('contact_date', 'desc')->get(); I also tried with different sub queries but same results. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should use `>` in your condition:

`whereDate('contact_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));`

Full code here:

```
Client::whereHas('messages', function($query){
    $query->orderBy('contact_date', 'desc')
    ->whereDate('contact_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
})->get();
```

Comment: I need dates less than not greater than the specified date